# "modern" title/abstract page with "twocolumn" remainder of document

Tags: document-classes, journal-publishing, journal

The American Astronomical Society has put out a [new template](http://journals.aas.org/authors/aastex/aasguide61.html) for typesetting their journal articles. It comes with two documentclass options, modern and twocolumn.

I like the "modern" style for the first page (title/abstract page) but prefer the "twocolumn" style for the remainder. Is it possible to switch between the two?